# How do I run IIS Express from the command line with "Enabled 32 bit applications" enabled?

Tags: windows-server-2008, webserver, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

**Problem:**

I have a website that I need to run which has a referenced DLL which is 32 bit.

Doing it through the IIS GUI, it's no problem *once* I've enabled 32 bit applications in the application pool.

[image: gui example]

However I'm not sure how to achieve this when running IIS Express. This is how I run the site at the moment.

`iisexpress /path:C:\site /port:59822`

Which when run gives the same error as doing it through the GUI would *if* I hadn't enabled 32 bit application.

[image: error screenshot]

**Question:**

I know what the error is, I know how to fix it through the IIS GUI, but due to the need for automation, I need to find a way to do this programmatically through `iisexpress.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Express 64-bit doesn't support `enable32BitAppOnWin64`, use the 32-bit IIS Express to use the 32-bit library.

You can do this by telling Visual Studio to use the 32-bit version...

```
 Tools
  -> Options
   -> Projects and Solutions
    -> Web Projects
     -> Uncheck "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"`
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30205247/225906)

Also, the files can be obtained manually:

> The 32 bit version can be found at `c:\program files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\iisexpress.exe` and the 64 bit version can be found at
>   `c:\program files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16226897/225906)